# How to connect parts of Rocket-Chip to put on altera FPGA

Tags: riscv

I am trying to map the riscv rocket-chip to an altera cyclone 2 FPGA. I am able to generate symbolfiles (with the software Altera Quartus 2) from the file Top.DefaultFPGAConfig.v with names like TOP, Uncore, Frontend, etc.. The problem I now have is, that I have no idea how I should connect them to each other to get a functioning rocket-chip. Is somebody already running a rocket-chip on an altera board?

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue of interfacing, and fortunately Rocket Chip speaks AXI so it should be tractable.

[Previous question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491842/rocket-chip-on-non-zynq-fpgas) about this