# Configuring Rocket Chip

Tags: fpga, riscv, rocket-chip

I want to build my own SOC based on the rocket chip without the use a ROCC(arm coprocessor). I checked this useful question: [rocket chip on non zynq FPGA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491842/rocket-chip-on-non-zynq-fpgas)
I looked for some detailed documentation but I only found few slides describing the configurations without an actual tutorial.
Thus, I have three questions concerning the image below:

[image: Rocket Chip]

- I managed to generate the overall verilog for the tinyConfig, but is it possible to generate only the Rocket Chip, HostIO/AXI Convertor and MemIO/AXIHP Convertor ? if yes how ?
- Can a debug interface be added by the rocket Chip generator ?
- Where can I change the RAM used in rocket chaip by a RAM of a specific FPGA vendor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verilog generated by rocket-chip can be used in FPGA. You just need to replace the behav_srams.v with the RAM generated in vivado.

In system/Config.scala, You can add class WithJtagDTMSystem to your config to generate debug interface.